# Tkinter Canvas callback forwards only positional string?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, callback

I have an array of Tkinter.Canvas objects, they all "bind" to the same "callback".

I used this following code to bind each Canvas to an identifier id.

But the callback function only receives an event string, providing the x,y position of the click within that particular Canvas, but certainly the "param" is not returned, unless I miss it somewhere.

Of course, I can use other widgets to do this, but the Canvas provides me with the flexibility of being able to draw shapes on it.

Here is the example code of what I am trying to do. I have an array of canvas, which I hope, clicking them, will return its id, however, all I can get is an string of positional information, not the id ("a", "b" or "c" ) at all. Even the positional information can not tell me which canvas it is from as it is the position within the canvas being clicked.

Don't know if there is a way for a canvas to return anything relating to itself specifically, when there are more than one canvas ?

```
import tkinter as tk

def doClick(a):
    print(a)            #tell what's being returned

mainW=tk.Tk()
mainW.geometry("220x220+20+20")

cb=[0,0,0]          # array of three canvas
cb[0]=tk.Canvas(mainW,width=50, height=50, bg="green")
cb[0].place(x=20,y=20)
cb[0].bind("<1>",lambda id="a" : doClick(id))
cb[1]=tk.Canvas(mainW,width=50, height=50, bg="yellow")
cb[1].place(x=40,y=40)
cb[1].bind("<1>",lambda id="b" : doClick(id))
cb[2]=tk.Canvas(mainW,width=50, height=50, bg="silver")
cb[2].place(x=60,y=60)
cb[2].bind("<1>",lambda id="c" : doClick(id))

mainW.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: please don't post code in the comment section. You can [edit]  your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When binding callbacks to widgets etc. tkinter sends event information to the callback function as well.

This is how you should use lambda on bindings.

```
cb[0].bind("<1>",lambda event, id="a" : doClick(id))
```

By the way, you don't need to initialize items in a list. You can do something like,

```
cb = []
cb.append(tk.Canvas(mainW,width=50, height=50, bg="green"))
cb[-1].place(x=20,y=20) #last appended item
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Perhaps, if you have the time, as I am new to Python etc.  Please point me to documentation or explain how it works in this case.

Comment: You can read [this one](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm). In short, when using lambda, objects/words between `lambda` and `:` are parameters for that anonymous function. For bindings, you need to have an extra `event` argument when defining a function. So, in this one, I added an event argument for that anonymous function.

Comment: Thanks.   I thought "event" is some sort of keyword.  I actually changed to "et", and it works fine.  So I understand it perfectly now.

Comment: Perhaps to help me understand this even better, when I added the attribute "Command" for a Button, for example, I used,

tk.Button(root,width-.....,command=lambda id="a" : doClick(id))

that the lambda function only use a single argument "id". 

What is the subtle difference in "bind()" and in setting the attribute "command" ?